# How to use parameters in contains method in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, contains, freetext

I am testing contains method in store procedure. I would like to see data result like:

**Example Result for John:**

- John Nick
- Papa John
- Harly John Fredy

I don't want to use LIKE method. Can we use starts with or ends with (*) operator with parameters in SP?

**CONTAINS(name,@name)** //  query is working

but if i can try like this:

**CONTAINS(name, '"john" OR "john*"')**  // query is working
**CONTAINS(name,'"@name" OR "@name*"')** // query is not working

With parameters same query is not working in SP. Is it posibble to do this in SP?

Thanks,

Comment: You could try putting the whole thing in a variable. For example, `DECLARE @nameX NVARCHAR(4000) = '"' + @name + '" OR "' + @name + '*"'` then using `CONTAINS(name, @nameX)`

Comment: ZLK, this looks like the right answer. Why don't you put it in the answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `CONTAINS`, in order to pass a wildcard through with a variable, you need to make the wildcard a part of the variable.

The easiest way to do it within a stored procedure is adding a variable (or modifying your current variable).

For example,

```
DECLARE @nameX NVARCHAR(4000) = '"' + @name + '" OR "' + @name + '*"'
...
CONTAINS(name, @nameX)
```